# amp-list with flexible height to a max

Tags: amp-html

I want to provide a list which will vary with the input of a text box. This list will provide the results for that search query. I am using amp-list for this.

I want the list height to adjust to the number of results (flex-item should be fine here). But I want the list to have a max height of e.g. 500px and no more

Is this possible? Thank you very much

Comment: Forgot to mention that if the list is larger than 500px, the user should have the option to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic resizing is currently in the works: see [this thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10230) on GitHub - although not sure if this applies in your current situation. Are you able to provide the code or a link to what you're currently working on?

To accomplish the max-height with an overflow of scroll, put a container div around the amp-list. Something like below.

```css
div#list-container {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <amp-list>
  </amp-list>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this suggested workaround and also worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use amp-bind to dynamically update the amp-list height based on the number of search results:

```
<amp-list layout="fixed-height"
  height="0"
  src="/results"
  [src]="searchResults"
  [height]="searchResults.length < 5 ? 100 * searchResults.length : 500">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    // search results
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

I assumed that a single search result has a height of 100px and that the results are contained in an amp-state variable called `searchResults`.

[Here is a working sample](https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/hotel/#rooms-list) demonstrating how to dynamically resize an amp-list.

Comment: the thing is to talk to someone who understands, hahaha, perfect