# amp-mustache template not rendering

Tags: amp-html, amp-list, amp-mustache

I have created an amp-mustache template as shown below.

```
<template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-id">
    <div>
        <span>{{date}}</span>
        <span>{{prev}}</span>
        <span>{{open}}</span>
        <span>{{low}}</span>
        <span>{{high}}</span>
        <span>{{last}}</span>
        <span>{{vol}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

This template in nested inside amp-list. amp-list has a source url (https and cross-origin) which is sending below JSON.

{
    "date": "2018-08-03 14:40:09",
    "prev": 37165.16,
    "open": 37327.16,
    "low": 37319.61,
    "high": 37567.47,
    "last": 37557.93,
    "vol": 0
}

On loading the page I cannot see anything. In DOM I can only see this empty div.

```
<div class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content" role="list"></div>
```

I followed the example mentioned in this [link](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/). I also tried replacing variables in between span tag as "date", ${{date}}, "prev", ${{prev}}  but nothing worked. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Adding the amp-list portion of the code

```
   <amp-list src="https://api.myjson.com/bins/133uw8" width="auto" height="auto" layout="responsive"> 
      <template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-id2">
           {{date}}----{{prev}}----{{open}}----{{low}}----{{high}}----{{last}}----{{vol}}
      </template>    
    </amp-list>
```

Comment: Are you wrapping the JSON array inside "items"? (ie; { "items": [{ YOUR DATA HERE }]}). Can you add the amp-list portion of your code to your post?

Comment: @craigscott - Even after wrapping the JSON array inside "items", I am unable to render the template. Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is here `width="auto" height="auto" layout="responsive"`

Responsive Layout need width and height because Element sized to the width of its container element and resizes its height automatically to the aspect ratio given by width and height attributes.

Here is more information about which layout use width and height [Click Here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/control_layout)

`amp-list` Support layout is : fill, fixed, fixed-height, flex-item, nodisplay, responsive

Json Should be like this : [Click Here](https://jsonblob.com/api/fd99f2cd-97cb-11e8-b9d3-3380a04270d1)

```
{
 "items": [
   { "date": "2018-08-03 14:40:09", "prev": 37165.16, "open": 37327.16, "low": 37319.61, "high": 37567.47, "last": 37557.93, "vol": 0 }
 ]
}
```

[Here is the working Url](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBebMm)

```
<!--
  ## Introduction

  The [`amp-list`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) component fetches dynamic content from a CORS JSON endpoint and renders it using a supplied template. This is good for embedding a dynamic list of related articles.
-->
<!-- -->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>amp-list</title>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!-- ## Setup -->
  <!-- Import the `amp-list` component ... -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
  <!-- ... and the `amp-mustache` component in the header -->
  <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>
<body>
<amp-list src="https://api.myjson.com/bins/133uw8" width="300" height="500" layout="responsive"> 
      <template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-id2">
           {{date}}----{{prev}}----{{open}}----{{low}}----{{high}}----{{last}}----{{vol}}
      </template>    
    </amp-list> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The big thing that stands out to me is your layout type and dimensions of your amp-list. I actually just put them into something I was working on and I get an error saying auto is invalid for the height value. This may be why nothing is rendering. Type responsive expects both a width and height and then it will constrain proportions when scaling.

For an amp-list you might be better suited to use a layout type of fixed-height or flex-item. If you use either you can leave your width undefined and then you just need to specify an exact height.

If you need your amp-list to have a somewhat dynamic height, check out the answer from Sebastian Benz in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614270/amp-list-with-flexible-height-to-a-max).

Comment: In our experience, `fixed-height` works best. We get irregular results with `flex-item`. @bachcha below shows a good solution, but he avoids the height issue with a single line layout.